# My @ key and " keys are swapped, how can I reconfigure my keyboard on my Samsung laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-layout

The @ key and " keys are swapped around on my Samsung laptop? Does anyone know how to change them back?

Comment: What do you mean they are swapped? What default keyboard layout do you have? What exactly are you pressing, what are you expecting, and what is the result?

Answer (score 1):

Change your keyboard settings from "English (US)" to "English (UK)".

Comment: or vice versa depending on what he or she is using now.